# jquery code when min-width set

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

i'm using [sticky.js](http://www.stickyjs.com) now i wanna use this when min-width sets to 768px in other words
i don't want sticky.js works in mobiles or devices that has max-width 768px .

i use this jquery code to use sticky-js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#header").sticky({
        className : 'sticky-header' ,
        topSpacing : -45
    });
});
```

if you need more details let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a condition, and check whatever element has the min-width style set

```
jQuery(function($){
    var min_width = parseInt( $('body').css('min-width'), 10 );

    if ( min_width > 768 ) {
        $("#header").sticky({
            className : 'sticky-header' ,
            topSpacing : -45
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry adeneo , i was in wrong .now plugin perfectly doesnt work . please see this bloodmyst.com